# Use colors or arrows to denote direction for d3SimpleNetwork for R

Tags: r, iframe, neural-network, igraph, direction

For R and D3Network, consider the following:

```
library(D3Network)
NWD <- head(Europe)
d3SimpleNetwork(NWD, file="a.html")

a <- c("A", "B", "C", "AA", "BB", "AA")
b <- c("B", "C", "A", "BB", "CC", "CC")
c <- data.frame(a,b)
d3SimpleNetwork(c, file="a.html")
```

This will create a plot that looks like this:

[image]

Note that both triangles look identical, while the relationships are different (AA->CC where C->A). I would like to be able to see the directions implied by the SOURCE and TARGET fields of d3SimpleNetwork to allow for something like this:

[image]

Since the dataframe c anyway knows what is a source and what is a target, is there any way to draw little arrows, or add a color gradient, or line-width or anything to denote direction on the links? If it's not possible using the library D3Network, is it possible in any other?

Answer (score 1):

Possible in the `igraph` library!

```
library(igraph)
betterC <- graph.data.frame(c)
E(betterC)$arrow.size <- .1
plot(betterC)
```

Gives the following:

[image]

Not as pretty, but it works! Hope this is useful to someone!

Comment: If would be prettier if you used some anti-aliases device.